# Semi-subjective question. Off topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that I want to ask, but I don't know if it would be too subjective.  Can I get an opinion as to whether or not this would be allowed?  text below:

> I applied for a couple of positions at different companies that I would like to work for, but after multiple interviews, didn't get either position.  However, feedback was overwhelmingly positive, so about a month after, I noticed that the positions were still open, and I contacted the hiring managers to see if I could re-apply.  They didn't have anything for me, but wanted me to keep in touch as I was able to show my commitment to improving and making myself better for their needs.  Now, I want to send a keep-in-touch email to them, to ask about new positions they may know of, or if they could use me in some position. However, I don't know how to write this up without sounding awkward.  Does anyone know of any templates I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase it thusly:

> **TITLE:** What is the appropriate way to follow up with employers
>
> This happened with several companies:
>
> - I had applied for a position
> - interviews went well
> - Feedback was positive
> - Didn't get job
> - Position was still open
>
> After reaching out to managers, they asked me to keep in touch as I improve myself.
>
> How should I structure follow up emails for this purpose?
> Is there any standard I should follow

Brief questions tend to get answered more quickly, and fully.

That said, it's absolutely on topic